# decompress LZString in server side(java)

Tags: javascript, java, compression, lzma, lz4

I am trying to send base64 details from client side(java script) to server(java). 
In order to reduce the base64 size, I am using lz-string.js as follow:

```
var base64Data = "0dYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6g";
var compressed = LZString.compress(base64Data);
```

As you aware Once it compressed by LZ the data will look like follow: [image]

Hence I am sending the data to server side by following Ajax call:

```
var formData = "img="+compressed";

    jQuery.blockUI();
    jQuery.ajax({
            url : "/myapplication/Saverequest",
        type: "POST",
        data : formData,
        cache: false,
        async:false,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        ");
```

I can able to retrive the data in my action class(java) as it is. But I cant decomplress the the data. 
I do requrie the same I sent !(refer : base64Data)

I did use few code in online regarding LZ (LZString.Java) but it is not decompressing the data!!

Please help me to find proper java libs where I can decompress this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The compressed data looks larger than your original data. Are you sure compressing it is useful. Note that asking for suggestions for libraries is off-topic.

Comment: Yes . it reducing.. I shared the the compression as sample look a like!! I am not just only asking libs but for the code or way to decompress this data in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by mentioning UTF-8 encode by follow:

1. in server.xml under config:

   Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1 connectionTimeout="20000"
    redirectPort="8443"  URIEncoding="UTF-8"
2. In HTML/JSP :

meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type

3. mentioning in java action class in the beginning:

   request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
4. Most importantly compress/decompress is not working for this. I have used 
   compressToUTF16/decompressFromUTF16. This getting outcome as UTF16 only works!